# Angular 2 Observables From PHP

Tags: php, angular, ionic2, rxjs

I'm a bit new to `Observables` in `Angular2`. From what I understand they will emit the changes to the `subscribers` whenever there's a change in data. I actually get the first response from my `php` backend on **initial run**.

> But if I change or update things on the database *`the observable cant fetch the next changes again. It will only update upon refresh`*

**My service**

```
checkField(_options : T):Observable<any>{
  this.options = _options;
  let x = this.serialize(this.options);

  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

  return this.http.post("http://zodiark.co.nf/php/check_id.php" , x , options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**My Component**

```
regChecker.checkField(this.checkerOption).subscribe( 
  (data) => { this.testObserver = data; console.log(this.testObserver)
})
```

> *I just need a clarification if this is possible*.
>   *PS. Thanks in Advance*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables are used in many places, there are many ways of understanding Observables but what you **do** need to understand, is that HTTP requests return an Observable that gets completed on response (or on failure), it can't actually know when your backend decides to "send" more data, because it's just not built that way, your backend only responds to requests.

Because of this, using observables for HTTP requests is almost exactly the same as using Promises for HTTP requests, with the exception of Observables being cancel-able.

In other use-cases for Observables the advantage will become clearer... I'm sure you'll find many examples with having DOM event observables, or angular2 reactive form controls' value observables and so on...

Hope I understood what you had missing on what's going on :)

Comment: Thanks. I got hot observable that broadcast time using `Observable.interval`. I understand what you're trying to imply. I thought I could do some sort of AngularFire2, I tried it before and changing directly on the database will reflect on the client. But thanks again.

Comment: Oh yeah, Firebase is so much more than a simple HTTP request ;)

Comment: Problem is I need to use the existing live website of the Desktop Version. So my Ionic app should fetch on that db with `php` >_<. Sad life haha

Comment: Indeed it is :{

Comment: Are you Ionic/Angular developer? How can I reach you If i need help in the future?

Comment: Just a developer, not a contributor or anything, I guess you could message me on gitter, or just open a question on here